# Problem when trying to upload images to Firebase Storage and Database?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm actually having a problem that I don't understand. To create this code i helped myself of a youtube tutorial, at the starting it works but then I get the error : [discovery] errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled"
and the images that are get from the users are not upload to firebase storage nor to firebase database. I'm new to xcode, can somebody tell 
me why ? ( And I don't get any error message ), it should save the image the user picked to firebase storage and then register the url of the image under the user uid in firebase database, thanks a lot to those who will take some time to read and to answer this. Here's my code :

```
import UIKit

import Firebase

class Profile: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var MyImageView: UIImageView!
    var selectedImage: UIImage?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:      #selector(Profile.handleSelectProfileImageView))
        MyImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        MyImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    @objc func handleSelectProfileImageView(){
        let pickerController =  UIImagePickerController()
        pickerController.delegate = self
        present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func OkButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        let storageBase = Storage().reference()
        let storageRef = storageBase.child("profile_image").child(uid)

        if let profileImg = self.selectedImage, let imageData =   profileImg.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1) {
            storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

                storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                    guard url != nil else {
                        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                        return
                    }                        // Get the download URL in Database
                    let ref = Database.database().reference()
                    let usersReference = ref.child("users")
                    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
                    let newUserReference = usersReference.child(uid)
                    newUserReference.setValue(["profileImageUrl": self.provideImageData])

                }
            })
        }
    }
}

extension Profile: UINavigationControllerDelegate,  UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        // Local variable inserted by Swift 4.2 migrator.
        let info = convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKeyDictionary(info)

        print("OKAY")
        if let image = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage{
            selectedImage = image
            MyImageView.image = image
            MyImageView.setRounded()
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension UIImageView {
    func setRounded() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = (self.frame.width / 2)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}

// Helper function inserted by Swift 4.2 migrator.
private func convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKeyDictionary(_ input: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) -> [String: Any] {
    return Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: input.map {key, value in (key.rawValue, value)})
}
```

Comment: In which part does it fail? Explain the process to reproduce. Also, always use camel case for instance variables (convention). So in your code this `@IBOutlet weak var MyImageView: UIImageView!` should be set to `@IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!` through the interface builder

Comment: I get the error : [discovery] errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" So there might be a problem in the extensions, but I've made some research and I didn't find anything to solve this error. But is there any problem inside the code that could explain why it doesn't upload the images to firebase storage nor to the database ?

Comment: Maybe defining the source type for the UIImagePickerController? Try also with changing `dismiss` for `picker.dismiss` in the extension for `Profile`